# Apache Storm Timeout Issues

Tags: timeout, tuples, apache-storm

We are using Storm 1.0.2 and have an issue with bad timeouts in two different completely unrelated projects.  And have verified these issues in 0.10 as well...

We have 2 different scenarios:

First.  No matter what we set the tuple timeout to, when that time elapses we get a number of tuples back as failed.  But ALL of them are less than the time-out time old.  For example if we set the timeout to 15 minutes (crazy high), the topology runs fine for 15 minutes procecessing thousands of tuples per minute, but exactly at 15 minutes we suddenly get a thousand or more fails.  When we trace the message IDs back to the original emitted tuple, we find that all of them were emitted in the previous few minutes.  There are no tuples that exceed the 15 minute timeout.  It's almost as if the system is, at the timeout, just randomly flushing out tuples in flight for no reason.

Second.  We have a topology that is getting fails back to the spout BEFORE the ack of the same message.  So, the sequence of events: Emit tuple, sleep in the spout for x seconds.  During that x seconds, the final bolt acks the tuple.  The spout wakes from the sleep.  The spout gets a fail for the tuple, and the very next call to the spout is the ack for the same tuple.  During this testing some timeouts did elapse for the tuple during the spout sleeping, however the ack from the bolt was BEFORE the timeout.  It's as if the messages to the spout as queued up as fails before acks, and it has no mechanism from pulling a queued-pending fail message because it just got an ack.  This is not consistent it seems.  Sometimes we don't get the fail message, but sometimes we do.  We could not figure out a pattern.

In both these scenarios, the solution is to not have a time-out.  We have been testing different things for a week now, and we've found that without a time-out, every single one of our messages are processed just fine, nothing is lost.  During one experiment we even ignored all the fails, and everything was still processed.  However we had thousands upon thousands of false-fails.  The problem is, the data we are processing is vetted to be 100% perfect and the system is error free.  In the real world, we want the fails to re-emit tuples for a few different retries, then to an error log . But if we can not count on the built-in mechanism of the time-out in Storm from handling time-outs properly then we are stuck having to build our own time-out mechanism in the spount ourselves.

Has anyone else experienced time-out issues like this?  Is this a "known" issue?  Are we maybe setting something not quite right in our Topologies?

Thanks

UPDATE...
Through trial and error, and a test topology that does nothing but have a number of bolt with a fixed sleep time, I beleive I may have figured out some sort of pattern as to what is happening.

The problem lies in the fact that the Storm system does not gaurantee message (tuple) processing order.  Not only does it not gaurentee it, it seems to have some element of randomzing the messages.  This randomization only occurs when we add paralelism to the bolts.  This is exaserbated by the fact that our spout pending setting was way too high.  The number of workers does not seem to affect this observation, it's only the paralelism of the bolts that affects things.

What I don't know (yet) is where the messages are getting delayed in the in the system.  Is it from the spout to the first bolt, or one of the bolts in between (I have 3 layers) or, is the message really getting done, but not passed back to the spout immediatly.

What my test topology has not shown yet, is how messages are timing out BEFORE the time-out.  The tests clearly show messages that ack back AFTER the timeout time though.  At this point I have to assume that the messages made their way through the bolt, but just didn't get ack'd back to the spout in time?  I need to set up a way to record each message's passage through the system.

So this brings us up to a rock and a hard-place.  The reason we have soo many pending, is because we have a topology with 7 or 8 layers of bolts.  When the pending number is low, of course we get no timeouts, but the bolts are not runing anywhere near capacity, and our throughput (messages/second) is not very good.  We try to paralellize the bolts such that each runs equally in the capacity calculations.  And once we reached a capacity equalization (no hot spots), then we started tuning other things, and one of those tuning measures is to increase tuple pending from the spout.  The idea is the queue for each bolt has always got messages; we don't want a bolt instance to go idle because there is nothin in the queue for it to do.

The problem for us, is not that the messages are out of order, it's the fact that we cannot seem to have ANY sort of time-out setting.  If we do, we get fails back to the spout that are not really fails.

Does anybody have any idea on why it is that we are experiencing these issues?  And what we could do to... well... not experience them?  Aside from no timeouts.

Comment: Are all of the system clocks synchronized?

Comment: We will check.  But these are VMs hosted in Azure (no HD Insight though) so I can't imagine they would be off more that a microsecond between them.  And, we were actually able to reproduce the issue in a local topology running on one machine, so this really can't be the problem.

Comment: The VMs on which Storm is running were all withing 1 second of each other.

Comment: An "Interesting" find we had this morning, which we think might be related:  We were able to observe that a single tuple emitted from the spout was ack'd by all the bolts in just a few seconds (expected timing), but the spout did NOT get the ack for some minutes later.  This is in one of our tests where the spout never sleeps, so it's not like it's caught in the nexttuple call being asleep.  The only thing we can think of, is because the tuple "branches" there are 3 chains of bolts that all must ack to mean the initial tuple is fully finished.  Could this be an indicator of the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that each bolt emits all tuples before it acks the anchor?

Comment: Yes; an ack or fail is the final code of each bolt.  We may have had a situation where one of the bolts was doing two acks of the same tuple, but we fixed that, and still observed the timeouts.

Comment: Which Spout do you use? If you implemented your own, how much time nextTuple() spend for every call? Isn't spout blocking for some resources without timeout?

Comment: It's a custom spout that extends Rich Spout.  The next tuple spends a few ms only; nothing blocking.